# how to resolve Redirection in laravel8?

Tags: php, laravel-8

The route is not redirecting the specified route in laravel8.

Here is my code that is defined in **web.php**:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return redirect()->route('login');
});
```

After hitting '/', I need to redirect to this route:

```
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
```

I was getting an error:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: yes i can access /login

Comment: This code looks okay. Maybe your browser cached previously other route? try to clear browser cache for your site. if this not helps, post routes file entirely plus output of `php artisan route:list `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to clear the cache:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

*Refs: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/34512#discussioncomment-564416*

Comment: "route:clear" this work for me thanks

Comment: "optimize:clear" Not working

Answer (score 1):

Just try

> php artisan optimize

or

> php artisan route:clear

or you can change redirect

from

> return redirect()->route('login');

to

> return redirect('/login');

Comment: i tryied but no luck

Comment: even i added dd() for "/" but still it showing same error

Comment: Just updated my answer, you can try new one